# Referencing JQuery ajax response after callback

Tags: jquery, ajax

in my form I am making an ajax call after the email input button loses focus. I am using the returned response data to populate a Modal. Then in the modal I users can click a button to choose which record they want and populate the form with that data. I am passing the data id on the button.

Everything works fine until I click on the button in the modal. I guess the ajax response is no longer available at that point?

So my question is: do I have to make another ajax call to look up the data again or is it still somewhere where I can reference it?

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('click', '.choosebtn', function () {
        console.log(this);
        $(".myModal").modal("hide");
        $('.myform').populate({
            response.DATA[event.target.id]
        }, {
            phpNaming: true,
            debug: true
        });
    });

    $('.email').blur(email_check);
});

function email_check() {
    var email = $('.email').val();
    var data = $('form').serialize();

    if (email == "" || email.length < 10) {
        $('.email').css('border', '3px ##CCC solid');
    } else {
        jQuery.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/managemembers/checkemail?format=json",
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                if (response.DATA) {
                    var trHTML = '';
                    $.each(response.DATA, function (index, value) {
                        trHTML += '<tr><td width="25%">' 
                        + value[0] + '</td><td width="25%">' 
                        + value[1] + '</td><td width="25%">' 
                        + value[2] + '</td><td width="25%">' 
                        + value[3] + '</td><td><button type="button" class="choosebtn" id=' 
                        + index + '>Choose</button></td></tr>';
                    });
                    $('.mytable').append(trHTML);

                    $(".myModal").modal("show");
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It's only available if you store it somewhere.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Answer (score 0):

`response` is local to the AJAX `success` function, so you won't have access in your `populate` function. A quick fix would be to assign the `response` to a global variable:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var ajaxResponseData;
    ..
    //Reference global in populate
    $('.myform').populate({ajaxResponseData.DATA......
    ..
    ..
    ..
    success: function (response) {
        ajaxResponseData = response;
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Have it in a variable now, but can't figure out how to format it properly. I think I have an array of structs because the response looks like this: Object { COLUMNS=[16], DATA=[22]} so how do I pull out just one record? I can't figure that out. I can do yourResponseVariable.DATA[event.target.id] but can't figure out how to have the columns too. Thanks!

Comment: How about `ajaxResponseData[0][0]`

Comment: I put in yourResponseVariable[event.target.id][event.target.id] cause I am passing the index on the button click. when I do that I get  yourResponseVariable[event.target.id] is undefined

Comment: Try `ajaxResponseData.COLUMNS[0]`

Comment: HMMM... sorry I am new to jquery so thanks for being patient with me. When I reference ajaxResponseData.COLUMNS[index] it brings up just the column name. What I am trying to do is reference the entire record with all the column names and all the data at that one index

Comment: So I would like my final result to be: {"COLUMNS":["ID","EMAIL"], "DATA":["11","anemail@me.com"]} or it could be name value pairs

Comment: You'll probably have to loop through the response, do a quick search for iterating JSON data results

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear where you are trying to access the response that you cannot, but no, you will not have access to it outside of the callback. However, you can save the response in a variable outside of the ajax call if you will need it later. Like this:

```
var yourResponseVariable;

jQuery.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/managemembers/checkemail?format=json",
   data: data,
   dataType: "json",
   cache: false,
   success: function (response) {
            if(response.DATA){
            var trHTML = '';

            $.each(response.DATA, function (index, value) {
                trHTML += '<tr><td width="25%">' + value[0] + '</td><td width="25%">' + value[1] + '</td><td width="25%">' + value[2] + '</td><td width="25%">' + value[3] + '</td><td><button type="button" class="choosebtn" id=' + index + '>Choose</button></td></tr>';
            });

            $('.mytable').append(trHTML);

            yourResponseVariable = response;

            $(".myModal").modal("show");
        }    
   }

});
```

You could also save a part of it instead instead of the entire response, depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I have it in a variable now and can access it. But I can't figure out how to make it formatted properly.

Comment: Thanks! Have it in a variable now, but can't figure out how to format it properly. I think I have an array of structs because the response looks like this: Object { COLUMNS=[16], DATA=[22]} so how do I pull out just one record? I can't figure that out. I can do yourResponseVariable.DATA[event.target.id] but can't figure out how to have the columns too. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to store the value you care about in a hidden field and use jQuery traversal functions to find it:

So currently in your markup, you end up with this snippet (among other stuff):

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="choosebtn" id='1'>Choose</button>
</td>
```

You could change it so you end up with this, with the hidden field containing the info you want:

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="choosebtn" id='1'>Choose</button>
    <input type="hidden" class="myValue" />
</td>
```

Then in js:

```
$(document).on('click', '.chooseBtn', function() {
    var myVal = $(this).siblings('.myValue').val();
});
```